# Count on radio button check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 sets of radio buttons and each set has 2 radio buttons having values Accept/Reject. The 2 radio buttons in a set will have the same name.

My requirement is: 
Whenever a user selects a radio button in a set counter should increase by 1. For eg. If a user selects accepts in a radio button group the counter is increased by one. If he again selects accepts in the second group the counter is again increased by 1. But If he changes his decision to reject in the 1st radio button group the counter should not increase.

The reason I am using this counter is to determine many unsaved changes the user has before he submits the form. Also, I cannot use onchange event on the radio button because if the radio button was already selected as accept and the user changes it to reject it should not increase the counter. But with onchange event it will.

Below is my code:

```
<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" value="Reject" type="radio">

<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" value="Reject" type="radio">

<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" value="Reject" type="radio">

<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" value="Reject" type="radio">
```

Please advice.

Comment: what have you done so far? show me the code. But I'd say you should create the counter variable above the function head of js so that it will retain values when increment is triggered.

Comment: HTML elements should have one and only `id`, even within the same "group" of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot solve the problem without keeping track of which buttons have been changed. So each radio group needs an index or id and you keep track of them in a map like this:

```
var changedGroups = {}

function countChange(groupIndex) { // called from onchange
    changedGroups[groupIndex] = true;
}

function numberOfChanges() { // called when you need the number of changes
    var result = 0;
    for (index in changedGroups) result++;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, I thought about that but then it looked performance intensive as well. Another thing I have in my mind is that every time user selects a radio button i.e onchange event calculate how many radio buttons are checked. var countChecked = $('input[type=radio]:checked').length . But another problem i have is i have pagination in place. So on a given page this thing works fine and it give you the correct number of unsaved changes. But when i moves to the second page it doesn't have anything checked and when users selects anything on it the counter gets sets back to 0 again.

Comment: As long as you don't have thousands of radio buttons, you really should not be concerned about performance here!

Comment: It can be few thousands in some cases

Comment: well, then try it. Most likely you will be able to handle tens of thousands as well this way. Remember that the number of changes will be small as long as the user does not check thousands of radio buttons. The changedGroups object will remain small and won't affect performance here.

Comment: I think you were right. I tried all ends and most dirtiest of hacks but tracking is what i ended up with. Although i used your approach but coded my way. But any how thanks. Posting my code as well in another comment

Comment: $('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){

   var certItemId = $(this)[0].id;
   var foundId = false;


   for(iCount=0;iCount<arrayUnsavedChangesArray.length;iCount++){
    if(certItemId==arrayUnsavedChangesArray[iCount]){
     foundId = true;
     break;
    }
   }

   if(!foundId){
    arrayUnsavedChangesArray.push(certItemId);
    countUnsavedChanges++;
   }

   $('#unsavedChanges').html(countUnsavedChanges+' unsaved changes');

  });

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
 $('.totleft').text($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length+'/'+($('input[type="radio"]').length/2))
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvx3nL9p/

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery you can use following logic.

```
var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=radio]").on('change',function(){
            changedRadio(this);
        });

    });

    function changedRadio(clickedEle)
    {
        if( $(clickedEle).val() == "Accept" )
        {
            count++;
        }
        alert(count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do

```js
$('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);

$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  $('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1.
<input id="a" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="b" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900db" value="Reject" type="radio">
<br/>
2.
<input id="c" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="d" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dc" value="Reject" type="radio">
<br/>
3.
<input id="e" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="f" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900dd" value="Reject" type="radio">
<br/>
4.
<input id="g" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" value="Accept" type="radio">
<input id="h" name="certItemIdRadio-8adb94f9516be1ac01517097980900de" value="Reject" type="radio">

<br/><br/>
No. of Selected Options: <span class="counter"></span>
```

Comment: This is what I was doing as well. But I have pagination in place. So lets say user moves to 2nd page which has nothing selected. And now the user selects the first radio button on that page then this code $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  $('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);
});   will count back to 1 again. I need to save what was clicked on page 1

Comment: I don't see how the number of checked radio buttons can tell you the number of changes. Or are all of them unchecked at the beginning?

Comment: @HiteshBhutani you didn't mention about pagination in your question, just about a counter which gets incremented when the value changes, for pagination you can add a parameter called selected in page link, pass it to next page with the current value and get the value to use it in next page.

Comment: @lex82 I have updated the code with a check in the beginning, I just tried to give a minimal understandable solution which can be modified as per requirement by the user.

Comment: I still don't get it. Let's say in the beginning you have 2 checked radio buttons. Then you uncheck them and check two OTHERS. The number of selected options will not have changed but four radio buttons have changed.

Comment: radio buttons with same name can not be unchecked completely, once you have selected any one from any group, the only way to change this is by selecting another from same group with same name. I implemented my solution based on this simple logic. Maybe you got confused with the radio button and check box behavior.